# I'm having some confusion about fee variable binding

Tags: javascript, scope

I've read some guides on scope in JS, but I don't quite get what's going on here.

This *does* work:

```
var b = 6;
function a(){
    alert(b);
}
a(); //alerts 6
```

However, this makes Firebug say "x is not defined"

```
var funcB = function(){
    alert(x);
}

function funcA(anonymous){
    var x = 10;
    anonymous();
}

funcA(funcB);
```

So why doesn't the free x variable in funcB get binded to the x declared to be 10 in the first line of funcA?

Thanks

Comment: `var` declares a **local** variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function in JavaScript has its own `Lexical Environment`: a map between identifiers (names) used within it, and specific variables (and functions) that either exist (in the outer scopes) or will be created within the scope of this function.

The key point is that Lexical Environment for a given function is created at the moment this function is defined - not when it's executed.

At your second example, *name* `x` mentioned within `funcB` doesn't have anything to map to - there's no variable named `x` in its own scope or the parent (outer) scopes. Unlike the first example, where `b` can be mapped to a local variable named `b`, living in the same scope function `a` lives.

And of course, `funcB` cannot (and shouldn't) know about lexical environments of other functions, as it cannot (and shouldn't) know whether it will be called from within these functions - or not.

Comment: "created when defined, not when executed".  That explains it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because `var` declares a local variable, only visible within the scope of the function where it is declared.

Whatever is inside the body of `funcB` doesn't see what is in the body of `funcA`, you have to be explicit (pass arguments), or declare `funcB` inside `funcA` to close over `x` (a closure).

So what you can do is make `funcB` take `x` as an argument:

```
var funcB = function(x) {
  alert(x);
};

function funcA(fn) {
  var x = 10;
  fn(x);
}

funcA(funcB);
```

Comment: But isn't the call to anonymous within the scope in which x is declared, i.e. in funcA?  I know I can use arguments to functions--this is just an experiment.

Comment: What was throwing me off was that I didn't know that free variables are bound during the creation of the function, _not_ the execution of the function.

Comment: @user3391564: JavaScript has lexical scope, not dynamic scope.